# Call via VOIP on PC using Android Phone with single sim

Tags: android, voip

Is it possible to create a websocket / VOIP that will connect to a device (android device) to make a call or a text message? is there an existing app for this or tutorial that i can base my project?

Im planning to create an app and web app that can access my phone to make calls and text.

Answer (score 0):

You can use XMPP based project to have a chat system and voice/video call 
.I recommend you to use [Ejabberd](https://www.ejabberd.im/) .it is so nice platform that provide amazing features like chat ,voice/video call and also it is massively scalable around 1 million connection I think in one node.

And you can use variety of Xmpp library in Android that you can see bellow link [XMPP Libraries](https://xmpp.org/software/libraries.html)

Comment: I will look into that. thanks for the suggestion. im thinking of WebRTC for voip? have you ever tried that platform?

Comment: No I didn't try it yet

Comment: @JohnGeliberte please accept my answer if it is usable for u